# Upload .sql file to remote server

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, vb.net

‌Our development team is working on different .net applications. 
‌They create new tables stored procedures and other objects and when they are done they need to upload changes in database which is remotely located.

M‌y Task is to create an application which compares both database objects (local and remote) and make changes in remote database.

‌so what i did was i created .net app which scripts all objects create .sql file with all changes 
‌
the .net application which connects to remote server over the internet and run .sql file which i generated.

‌Every time the script checks whole database drop all objects which dont have data like stored procedure , views , types etc and recreate them 
‌
It goes well the .sql file handles every thing very well but the problem is that its too slow

a‌ .sql file with 48k line of code takes about 25 minutes to run remotely 
‌
n‌ow i need solution to increase the speed . what i thought was to upload .sql file which is of 1mb and then run it on server side but i cant do it manually as it will ruin the whole concept i want my app to upload the file and run it 
Please suggest and if you have any better approach please do let me know that too 
Thanks
Sample Sql Code is Given Below

```
  IF object_id('TBU_BankWithdrawalVoucher', 'U') is null 
Create Table [dbo].[TBU_BankWithdrawalVoucher](
    [PKGUID] uniqueidentifier  Not Null , 
    [AutoID] int Identity (1, 1) Not Null , 
    [VNo] nvarchar (255)  Not Null , 
    [VDate] datetime  Not Null , 
    [RecNo] nvarchar (255)  Not Null , 
    [RefNo] nvarchar (255)  Not Null , 
    [AccountDID] uniqueidentifier  Not Null , 
    [CashRegisterDID] uniqueidentifier  Not Null , 
    [Remarks] nvarchar (255)  Not Null , 
    [Amount] money  Not Null , 
    [CB] uniqueidentifier  Not Null , 
    [CDate] datetime  Not Null , 
    [MB] uniqueidentifier  Not Null , 
    [MDate] datetime  Not Null , 
    [DB] uniqueidentifier  Not Null , 
    [DDate] datetime  Not Null , 
    [BranchID] smallint  Not Null , 
    [RowVer] RowVersion Not Null , 
    [ISD] uniqueidentifier  Not Null , 
    [AppType] smallint  Not Null ) 
Go

IF OBJECT_ID('DF_TBU_BankWithdrawalVoucher_PKGUID', 'D') IS Not NULL 
    Begin
        ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TBU_BankWithdrawalVoucher] Drop CONSTRAINT [DF_TBU_BankWithdrawalVoucher_PKGUID]
    End
Go

IF OBJECT_ID('DF_TBU_BankWithdrawalVoucher_VNo', 'D') IS Not NULL 
    Begin
        ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TBU_BankWithdrawalVoucher] Drop CONSTRAINT [DF_TBU_BankWithdrawalVoucher_VNo]
    End
Go

IF OBJECT_ID('DF_TBU_BankWithdrawalVoucher_VDate', 'D') IS Not NULL 
    Begin
        ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TBU_BankWithdrawalVoucher] Drop CONSTRAINT [DF_TBU_BankWithdrawalVoucher_VDate]
    End
Go

IF OBJECT_ID('DF_TBU_BankWithdrawalVoucher_RecNo', 'D') IS Not NULL 
    Begin
        ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TBU_BankWithdrawalVoucher] Drop CONSTRAINT [DF_TBU_BankWithdrawalVoucher_RecNo]
    End
Go

IF OBJECT_ID('DF_TBU_BankWithdrawalVoucher_RefNo', 'D') IS Not NULL 
    Begin
        ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TBU_BankWithdrawalVoucher] Drop CONSTRAINT [DF_TBU_BankWithdrawalVoucher_RefNo]
    End
Go

IF OBJECT_ID('DF_TBU_BankWithdrawalVoucher_AccountDID', 'D') IS Not NULL 
    Begin
        ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TBU_BankWithdrawalVoucher] Drop CONSTRAINT [DF_TBU_BankWithdrawalVoucher_AccountDID]
    End
Go

IF OBJECT_ID('DF_TBU_BankWithdrawalVoucher_CashRegisterDID', 'D') IS Not NULL 
    Begin
        ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TBU_BankWithdrawalVoucher] Drop CONSTRAINT [DF_TBU_BankWithdrawalVoucher_CashRegisterDID]
    End
Go
```

Comment: 1) Why not use Sql Server Data Tools and 2) why do you think uploading the file will make the operations faster?

Comment: uploading the file and then run it on remote server makes it very fast it takes about 8 sec i did it manually to check

Comment: https://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/index ?

Comment: How are you running the file locally? The only significant time taken should be for the actual database operations. Can you show a small example of a part of the sql file that is slow?

Comment: can you please explain what sql server data tools

Comment: i ve added some .sql code

Comment: SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh272686(v=vs.103).aspx

Comment: "M‌y Task is to create an application which compares both database objects (local and remote) and make changes in remote database." It's been done, it's called `sqlpackage.exe`. Package your database as a DACPAC and `sqlpackage` can determine what commands to run to get another database to look the same way.

Comment: Ok, can you explain how "upload .sql file which is of 1mb and then run it on server side" works? Are you uploading it to the database server and using `sqlcmd`, to execute it, for example? Have you added instrumentation to the script to see which bits are slow? Looking at the sql you added the only overhead of running it remotely should be sending the command file to the server/

Comment: The remote server is dedicated server i have full access to that server. i just opened it through remote admin uploaded my file manually and run it in management studio (its just like running it in local server)

Comment: so i assume this could be done through ftp and sql cmd

Comment: i ve just looked a bit in SQL Server Data Tools. its a great tool shame that i didnt know about it but there is a bit of a problem. i always have to add some custom code to each table and some stored procedures, types etc . will it be possible in SSDT

Comment: 1. You can use sqlcmd.exe to run the script on remote server right from you local server. It can be slower only if you have slower network connectivity.
2. You can old school Windows > "Task Scheduler" on both server Local and remote. On Local, make the task run every hour, copy the "RunMe.sql" file to remote server. On Remote server, make the task run every hour, if the file exist in a specific folder say "c:\run_this_Script\". Run the script.
You can use Batch Files to do all the work like add copy/move/run sqlcmd.exe/etc. Hope it helps!